# Async File Save Await does not "Await"

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, win-universal-app

I apologize if this is a dupe. I couldnt find anything that dealt specifically with my issue.  Im trying to save a file using "await SaveAsync". I get this error Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) I assume its because it attempted to move on before an action completed... but shouldnt it wait because I used "await"?

Here is my code

```
try
        {
            if (CurrentFile == null || !_existingDocument)
            {
                await _generateDoc();
                return;
            }

            var docGen = new CustDocument(_inputs);

            docGen.Save(CurrentFile);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
```

And my method

```
 private async Task<StorageFile> _generateDoc()
    {

        var docGen = new CustDocument(_inputs);
        var savePicker = new FileSavePicker();

        savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("dptx File", new List<string>() {".dptx"});
        savePicker.SuggestedFileName = _inputs.CustomerName.Replace(" ", "").Trim();

        var file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync(); // Error here

        docGen.Save(file);
        return file;
    }
```

Stack Track (Not Much)

```
   at Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker.PickSaveFileAsync()
```

at MdTool.ViewModel.RmViewModel.<_generateDoc>d__6.MoveNext()

Comment: You're not awaiting *saving* the file - you're awaiting *picking* the filename, by the looks of it... Now, why have you assumed that the problem is that `await` hasn't worked properly? And is the error *actually* within `PickSaveFileAsync` or is it in `Save`?

Comment: Hi Jon, I assume that because code immediately throws the error at that point. On web findings I saw a similar issue where the error was due to the async code continuing to run before the file save had completed. So the answer is PickSaveFileAsync.

Comment: I suggest you don't assume anything. But you should post the full stack trace in your question.

Comment: That good advise :) I would never completely assume anything. Just speculating on a hunch... Adding the stack trace to the top. Not much there.

Comment: Well given that the exception is in PickSaveFileAsync itself, you never get as far as awaiting it as far as I can see...

Comment: I suggest you try to come up with an absolutely minimal repro of it.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, he especially needs to delete all code that never runs. Confusing right now.

Comment: Are calling on a background thread? You can only can this method from the UI thread.

Comment: I hadnt considered that Peter. It is calling from a background thread. Thanks for the extra pair of eyes guys. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

FOUND IT!
Here
[Using FileSavePicker with MessageDialog's IUICommand event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176469/using-filesavepicker-with-messagedialogs-iuicommand-event)

Would have never thought that it had to do with the dialog box.  To all who responded... Thanks for the help