# Call MessageDialog from Property Changed handler Store App

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, unauthorizedaccessexcepti, messagedialog

I'm trying to call a `MessageDialog` out of a `PropertyChanged` Handler. The first call is always successful, but when the `Dialog` gets called a second time, I get an `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

I've tried to wrap the call in a `Dispatcher`, but I got the same behavior.

Here's the code (snippet of `MainPage.xaml.cs`):

```
void PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
  {
    showMessage("Message", "Title");
  });
}

async void showMessage(String message, String title)
{
  MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog(message, title);
  await dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

Could anybody please help me with this issue?

Comment: This looks the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722490/messagedialog-showasync-throws-accessdenied-exception-on-second-dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that multiple property changes will cause multiple calls to display the dialog.  You should only ever display one dialog at a time:

```
bool _isShown = false;
async void showMessage(String message, String title)
{
    if (_isShown == false)
    {
        _isShown = true;

        MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog(message, title);
        await dialog.ShowAsync();

        _isShown = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, with the flag it works. I had also the Problem that i got two PropertyChanged Listeners on the same object and so the dialog was fired twice at the second try.